# Nested template issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, nested, jquery-templates

please check the below code what i have in my aspx page. Please help me in this.

I am trying to nesting one template into another but i am not getting proper output.

**My output:**

Application1

#childTemplate

****My expected output:****
Application1

Env1
Env2

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var mydata:[{Application: "Application1",Environment[{Env:"Env1"},{Env:"Env2"}]}];

$("#parentTemplate").tmpl(mydata).append("#divEnvironment"); 
});

<script id="parentTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<ul><li>${Application}</li></ul>
{{tmpl{$data} "#childTemplate"}}
</script>

<script id="childTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
{{each Environment}}
<p>${Env}</p>
{{/each}}
</script>

<div id="divEnvironment"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please add your expected output? Also, are those fragments included in the same file? Or are they in different files?

Comment: added my expected output. all are in single file

Comment: i have given here single json in put data like this i will have 3 to 5 rows